# right way to define Conway's law

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, microservices

First I wonder to know Conway's law refers to physical structure of an organization or relational structure in an organization and second I did not get what does fowler means in his article:

> When looking to split a large application into parts, often management focuses on the technology layer, leading to UI teams, server-side logic teams, and database teams. When teams are separated along these lines, even simple changes can lead to a cross-team project taking time and budgetary approval. A smart team will optimise around this and plump for the lesser of two evils - just force the logic into whichever application they have access to. Logic everywhere in other words. This is an example of Conway's Law[5] in action.

Comment: What do you mean by physical structure? Maybe the essence that Fowler said is that if you split an organization in a wrong way, e.g. based on tech, and not based on business domains, then it will yield a messy architecture since teams try to do shortcuts at the expense of modularity and well-defined responsibility. Of course, this can also happen if the structure is based on ad-hoc "business domains".

Comment: @DavidSzalai I mean in a company, they dispart different parts, like u said split base on tech. But i heard someone told me it is only on communication rather than the structure of teams

Comment: Basically the communication is what matters, but it is inherently harder to communicate effectively with the wrong team structure.

Answer (score 0):

I start answering the second part of the question. What Fowler is trying to say, or what I understand, is that when it comes the time to split a project into parts (like splitting a monolith into microservices), then you probably face the problem to split a big team into smaller teams and you do it around business skills or capabilities, not around technologies.

If your company is grouping people by skill or technology layer, you will have a team of devops, a team of frontends, a team of backends, and no one of them will be able to handle a single project: this will force you to have a siloed application (a.k.a. a monolith), because each team depends on each other to be able to fully complete a requirement and scaling will be very difficult. When you hire a new devops, you will just increase the devops team size. When you add a new feature, you will just increase your monolith size. That's the relation Conway is talking about.

On the other side, if you organize your company by mixing up all of those technologies and creating self-sufficient teams you will have each team composed by, for example, 1 devops, 2 backend and 1 frontend. Now, you can actually split your monolith into micro-services and scale as much as you want. When you need a new microservice, you can create a brand new team and ideally no one is affected by this action.

I agree with David when he says that communication is what matters, but it has to be provided the right way.